# Looking for substitute to the namespace "UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem;" in unity engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I'm looking for something which can replace `UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem`

I want to avoid external solutions like *Mirror* or *Photon*.
Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In case you are just asking because of the deprecation problem, I would advise you to wrap the methods in `UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem` and write your application code on top of it. When the new Networking stack is released, there will be an equivalent set of methods and it will likely take just a couple of minutes to replace the wrapper implementation with the new system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityEngine;
public class NetworkServerUI: MonoBehaviour {
 private void OnGUI() {
  string ipaddress = Network.player.ipAddress;
  GUI.Box(new Rect(10, Screen.height - 50, 100, 50), ipaddress);
  GUI.Label(new Rect(20, Screen, height - 35, 100, 20), "Statuss:" + NetworkServer.active);
  GUI.Label(new Rect(20, Screen, height - 35, 100, 20), "Connected:" + NetworkServer.connections.count);
 }

}